# Printing a motif on felt

Tags: felt, printing

I would like to print a motif on a polyester felt. I have the motif drawn in a vector graphic file on my computer, and would like to transfer it on the felt. What techniques are available to do so?

Comment: Is this a standalone image or is it a pattern that you're planning to trace?

Comment: I is an single "image" ~5x5cm but not a picture, more like a monochromatic motif.

Comment: The point of my question is to ascertain whether the quality of the printing matters... if you're going to trace it over or paint over it, the quality doesn't really matter. If it's going to be a standalone image, then the quality matters very much. Another question - how nappy is your felt? Some felts are pretty smooth, others are really fuzzy.

Comment: It will be a standalone image, so quality matter. My felt is quite flat not much fibre are going out of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Screen printing can be done successfully on felt, but it takes a little bit of experimentation due to the rougher texture of the fabric. Screen printing is also useful for making multiple copies of an image - unsure if you plan to make just one or multiple.

Comment: Could you recommend a reference on the subject? I have very little experience with screen printing at home.

Comment: There is a huge range of screen printing tutorials available online - mostly with t-shirts in mind. The following instructable is a good intro into standard photo-emulsion screen printing.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Screen-Printing-3/

You may need to experiment a bit with the thickness of your paint, number of passes, etc to get a clear image due to the texture of the felt.